# disable all clicks in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sliding

In my application I have slidingPaneLayout

```
 <com.abc.qwe.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_size"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@color/main_blue_color">

            <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:divider="@color/menu_list_divider_color"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_list"
                    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/aaa
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.abc.qwe.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

When slidingPaneLayout is opened I want disable all clicks, swipes any actions in FrameLayout.

When slidingPaneLayout is closed I want enable all clicks, swipes any actions in FrameLayout.

How could I do this?

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.aaa);
                for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
                    child.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

I did this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Look on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6238923/1020530

Comment: check my edited answer. I did like this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `onClickListener` , check if the slidingPanelLayout is opened or not,

```
if (opened){
   return ;
}
```

you may assume it is opened/ closed , when the offset of the slidingPanelLayout is 0 or equal to the screen width.

Comment: Wich onClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

in your .java file
implement what ever you wanna do with pane in onPanelClosed and onPanelOpened methods.

```
public static View _View;
public static SlidingPaneLayout _Pane;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    _View =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_list, container, false);
    _Pane = (SlidingPaneLayout) _View.findViewById(R.id.sp);

    _Pane.setPanelSlideListener(new PaneListener());
    return _View;
}





private class PaneListener implements SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener {

    @Override
    public void onPanelClosed(View view) {
        System.out.println("Panel closed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelOpened(View view) {
        System.out.println("Panel opened"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffSet) {
        System.out.println("Panel sliding");
    }

}
```