# How to disable clicks on YouTubePlayerView?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I want to implement YouTube Player View on my app, but since my app is an alarm clock, i don't want the user to be able to pause/stop the video or to change the volume. I tried to put a view on the YouTube Player View to block the clicks on it, but i guess that it's against the google policy because when i do that the video is not playing. I also tried:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/ypvAlert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard_button_size"
        android:clickable="false" />
```

But it's not working.  Is there something i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464718/2614364), you can disable click events on a view and all its children by setting `enable` to `false` with `view.setEnabled(false)` for each child. Call it in `onInitializationSuccess` callback :

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    enableDisableView(mYoutubeplayerView, false);
    mPlayer = youTubePlayer;
    mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
    mPlayer.loadVideo("63kmMcHBQlA");
}
```

Here is a complete working example :

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    String mApiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

    YouTubePlayerView mYoutubeplayerView;

    YouTubePlayer mPlayer;

    /**
     * disable all click event : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464718/2614364 by Parag Chauhan
     *
     * @param view
     * @param enabled
     */
    public static void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
        view.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < group.getChildCount(); idx++) {
                enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mYoutubeplayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.ypvAlert);
        mYoutubeplayerView.initialize(mApiKey, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        enableDisableView(mYoutubeplayerView, false);
        mPlayer = youTubePlayer;
        mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
        mPlayer.loadVideo("63kmMcHBQlA");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPlayer.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested the sample code above on Android 4.4 & Android 6 and can't pause the video. It's working on the emulator too

Comment: You right. I guess i changed the order of the code lines inside onInitializationSuccess and this is why it didn't work. Now it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line

```
youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
```