# Hide fragment by translucent layout

Tags: java, android, user-interface, clickable

My requirement is-
I have created a layout in a fragment which has a UI. I have to hide that UI by a translucent image or layout or something so that actual UI become unclickable. UI should still be visible, just unclickable.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simply done by `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   // Your fragment Content goes hre

  </LinearLayout>
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_Translucent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#33000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Just set `rel_Translucent` to `VISIBLE` whenever you want translucent overlay.

Comment: If I do what you have said then in that case Relative layout will cover whole fragment bcz its width is match_parent. And the fragment's actual UI that I want to show will disappear.
Just FYI, I tried the same solution. :p

Comment: Then just put that part of UI inside `RelativeLayout` . Whats the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want without adding an extra view. You can disable the click events by set enabled to false.

you can use the function mentioned by Parag Chauhan in the answer below:

[How to disable all click events of a layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238881/how-to-disable-all-click-events-of-a-layout)

Hope this will help.